# Easier way to convert string of ascii numbers to string of letters?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

so I have the string "116,101,115,116,49,50,51,52" and I want to convert it from ASCII decimals to ASCII letters. This is the code I'm using to do that:

```
    String charInts = "116,101,115,116,49,50,51,52";
    String[] tokenizedCharInts = charInts.split(",");
    String phrase = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < tokenizedCharInts.length; i++) {
        int digit = Integer.parseInt(tokenizedCharInts[i]);
        phrase += (char) digit;
    }
    System.out.println(phrase);
```

It works so I'm fairly happy with it, but I'm wondering if anyone knows a more elegant way of doing this instead, perhaps without using that for loop (having to convert each split string to an int, then a char, then append it, for every small sub-string, makes me feel like their must be a cleaner solution).

Answer (score 0):

Using `StringBuilder` and other `for` maybe? :

```
 String charInts = "116,101,115,116,49,50,51,52";
 String[] tokenizedCharInts = charInts.split(",");
 StringBuilder phrase = new StringBuilder();
 for (String a : tokenizedCharInts) {
        phrase.append((char)Integer
                .parseInt(a));
    }
System.out.println(phrase);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an enhanced for loop, since you don't need the array element index.

You should use a StringBuilder to accumulate the string instead of `String phrase`, to avoid repeated string construction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Scanner` and `StringBuilder` combo : (no need to split the String and loop though it.)

```
      String charInts = "116,101,115,116,49,50,51,52";
      Scanner scanner=new Scanner(charInts);
      scanner.useDelimiter(",");
      StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

      while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        sb.append((char)scanner.nextInt());
      }
     scanner.close();
     System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Java-8 solution:

```
String charInts = "116,101,115,116,49,50,51,52";
String phrase = Arrays.stream(charInts.split(",")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
    .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
    .toString();
System.out.println(phrase);
```

Comment: Java 8 is soooooo different

Answer (score 0):

**IF** this fits your use-case:

```
char[] charInts = new char[] { 116,101,115,116,49,50,51,52 };
String s = new String(charInts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Java provides an elegant, single-line solution using Streams API.

```
String charInts = "116,101,115,116,49,50,51,52";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Arrays.stream(charInts.split(","))
    .map(Integer::parseInt)
    .map(Character::toChars)
    .forEach(sb::append);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```